# Multiple tax_queries: display posts titles from several custom taxonomie

Tags: wp-query, tax-query

Im trying to get this work. They do individually.

```
function render_main_menu (){
    $cpt = 'mycpt';
    $tax = 'section';
    $term = 'main';
    $tax2 = 'paragraph';
    $term2 = 'sub';

    $loop = new WP_Query(array (
    'post_type' =>  $cpt,
    'posts_per_page'    =>  -1, 
    'order'         =>  'ASC',
    'orderby'       =>  'menu_order',
    'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    //works with only one taxonomy
    //https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
    //Display posts from several custom taxonomies:
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $tax,               
            'field' => 'slug',                   
            'terms' => array( $term ),
        ) //, there was a missing comma here (as spotted by @PieterGoosen)
        //querying both the arrays --> blank screen
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $tax2,               
            'field' => 'slug',                   
            'terms' => array( $term2 ),
        )
    )
    )); 

    ?>
    <div class="main_menu_line2">
    <table>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    //...etc then close
 add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'render_main_menu', 15 );
```

thank you

Comment: Are you sure you need the `AND` relation and not `OR`

Comment: well Im not focused on that line for now. I can as well comment it out. I just want to get rid of the blank screen when I try to query more then one taxonomy.

Comment: You are missing a comma after your first array in your `tax_query`. You should follow the error messages your code throws. Turn debugging on

Comment: @PieterGoosen totally! thank you, thank you, thank you :)

Comment: My pleasure, glad your issue is resolved. Enjoy ;-)